# Is it safe to use Locale as a way to store "Country" and "Language"

Tags: locale

Wikipedia says that locale dictates a set of formatting rules for a specific language/region combination so it doesn't contain timezone or daylight savings information.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale

This leads me to believe that it would be a bad practice to derive the country and language elements independently and make use of them for other purposes like sorting data by a specific country.

Is it safe to say that locale doesn't map to a specific geographic location and therefore shouldn't be used to associate data to a geographic location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to say that locale is not connected to location, yes.

For example, a Japanese businessman in San Diego would be using his laptop set to a Japanese locale.

Likewise, a US businessman visiting China would be using a US locale.

Comment: And a lot of Spanish-speaking US citizens in the US will have a locale like es_ES, since es_US is rarely supported … even if s/he never has any intention of going anywhere near Spain; likewise, a Chinese-speaking US citizen might have (zh_CN? I'm not sure?) I gather that, e.g. a New Zealand resident might use en_UK (or even en_US) for similar reasons, &c.